# How to list Department with Highest GPA from table with list of GPAs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am able to make a table that shows me the GPA of each Department, but I am not sure how to make it display only the department with the highest GPA.

My query is:

```
SELECT avg(grade) as GPA, deptID from tblStudent s inner join tblTranscript t
ON t.studentid = s.studentid
group by deptID
```

Comment: add `ORDER BY avg(grade) DESC LIMIT 1` to get the `deptID` with highest GPA and then join back with `department` table to get department details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This for MYSQL**

```
SELECT deptID, GPA
FROM(
    SELECT deptID, AVG(grade) AS GPA 
    FROM tblStudent s 
    INNER JOIN tblTranscript t ON t.studentid = s.studentid
    GROUP BY deptID ) t ORDER BY GPA  DESC LIMIT 1
```

**IF you are using SQL-SERVER**

```
SELECT TOP 1 deptID, GPA
FROM(
    SELECT deptID, AVG(grade) AS GPA 
    FROM tblStudent s 
    INNER JOIN tblTranscript t ON t.studentid = s.studentid
    GROUP BY deptID ) t ORDER BY GPA DESC
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying Syntax error in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: It should definitely work if you are using MySQL, so please share sample data and expected output.

Comment: So, you can try with second one. it should work in Access as well.

Comment: You are welcome, please update tag in the question as well so that we can provide answer on tagged DBMS. You can also vote up and accept the question, if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways

**EITHER**:

```
SELECT MAX(avg(grade)) as GPA, deptID from tblStudent s inner join tblTranscript t
ON t.studentid = s.studentid
group by deptID
```

**OR**

Like @ughai said in this comment

```
SELECT avg(grade) as GPA, deptID from tblStudent s inner join tblTranscript t
ON t.studentid = s.studentid
group by deptID ORDER BY avg(grade) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: in the* comment

Comment: The first one says cannot have aggregate function in expression and the second says syntax error in Order clause

Comment: try ORDER BY GPA DESC LIMIT 1 instead of ORDER BY avg(grade) DESC LIMIT 1. Hope it helps.

Comment: It has something to do with the word Limit

Comment: If you have to display dept with highest GPA, I think removing `GROUP BY` clause from the query would work as well

Comment: That didn't do anything. The limit clause is causing a problem, if I just order by desc it shows the the gpa highest to lowest, how do I just show the highest one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129867/discussion-between-anish-chikodi-and-chacol).